# Rails deploys to a subdirectory failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As the document says

config.relative_url_root = "/app1"
Rails will now prepend "/app1" when generating links.

I did it in the application.rb

But all the generated paths don't have the prepend prefix

for example root_path should be `/app1` but it's still be `/`

## application.rb

```
module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
    config.relative_url_root = "/app1"
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you reload you web server? And how did you check your routes?

Comment: the generated links  by url_helper, root_path, product_path, just don't work~

Comment: I restarted the server many times